# how to get attributes from win32com.client.dispatch("Shell.Application")

Tags: python, windows-7, win32com

I am trying to control my device manager programmatic through python (ie disable and re-enabling devices). However I am having trouble figuring out what are the attributes in the namespace of the "win32com.client.Dispatch("Shell.Application")". All i know how to do is get the name and print it. I did a debugging run through the code but i couldn't find anything useful.

Here is what I have so far

```
    import win32com.client
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("Shell.Application")
    control_panel = shell.Namespace(3)
    for item in control_panel.Items():
        if item.Name == "Device Manager":
            print item
            break
```

this wasn't very useful either:

```
 control_panel.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 516, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
 AttributeError: <unknown>.GetNamespace
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to check the attributes in a COM object is using the `combrowse.py` available on `win32com\client` in your python site-packages folder

Just run the script (double clicking or from command line/python) and a window should appear with all the available com objects. Under `Registered Type Libraries` you should find the Shell under the correspondent Library in `Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation`
You can check this with the following command in python:

```
from win32com.client import gencache
shell = gencache.EnsureDispatch('Shell.Application')
print shell
```

Also, using the `gencache` method, you can use `Tab` to check some of the available methods, but for a comprehensive list check the `combrowse.py`. The only issue is that some of the methods listed at the `combrowse.py` are not really available within python.