# change the icon of a windows shortcut .lnk file using python

Tags: python, windows, icons, lnk

I want to change the icon of a `.lnk` file after I have created it. This is my main code so far:

```
import win32com.client

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut("shortcut.lnk")
shortcut.Targetpath = "C:\\Users\Benjie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe"
shortcut.save()
```

This creates a shortcut with the python icon, but I want to change it to a different icon, if possible, to the icon of a different `.exe` file.
How can I do this?

I'd preferably use one of the windows api librarys, but if this is not possible, an external library would work aswell.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, after a few hours of researching stuff with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081928/how-to-get-attributes-from-win32com-client-dispatchshell-application), I managed to find what I was looking for: `shortcut.IconLocation`. This sets the icon of a shortcut to an icon from an .exe, .dll .icl or .ico file. For example:

```
import win32com.client

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shortcut = shell.CreateShortcut("shortcut.lnk")
shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\\Users\Benjie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe"
shortcut.IconLocation = "C:\path_to_.exe,1"
shortcut.Save()
```

The icon path is a path to the file, with a comma and the number of the icon in the file. You can see the icons for a file if you create a shortcut and change its icon in its properties, Then browse for the file.