# Python change the icon of an existing windows shortcut

Tags: python, icons, lnk

I wanted to modify the icon of an already existing Windows shortcut (aka a `.lnk` file) using an externally created `.ico` file, and not one provided by Windows itself (by this I mean using an icon preferably located in the same folder as the `.py` file)

I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47369501/change-the-icon-of-a-windows-shortcut-lnk-file-using-python), but it only modifies the icon of shortcuts created from scratch with Python instead of replacing the icon of existing ones

Comment: The question that I have linked to is also able to change `.lnk` files that aren't created with Python, and an `.ico` file by itself can be used, you must find its absolute path by using `%USERPROFILE%` + the path to your file